# How to Sort Variables and Use it Properly in Unity?

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, unity-game-engine

I've been working on this for so long but unfortunately, I'm not progressing at all. I am creating a personality quiz in Unity wherein each question have choices where in depending on each choice, a certain variable is increasing in value. The quiz seeks to show the user's top 5 best fit patterns (which is the variable with the highest value) based on his personality which will be based upon his answers. The public voids are called depending on which choice/button was clicked through the on click in the inspector.

```
public class QuizScript : MonoBehaviour {

public int snake = 0;
public int centipede = 0;

public void Q2C1() //question 2 choice 1
{
    snake = snake + 1;
    Debug.Log("Snake = " + snake); //for me to see if it works
}

public void Q3C1() //question 3 choice 1
{
    centipede = centipede + 1;
    Debug.Log("Centipede = " + centipede);
}
}
```

There are 26 patterns in all but in the mean time, I just want to sort two variables which are the snake and the centipede. I have searched for tutorials about sorting variables and there are short and long methods. But either way, I am having a hard time understanding it and applying it in my code. In one method, it is required to use another public static void or static int to do the sorting, but what confuses me is how will I be able to call it inside another public void which will be the one called and done when the button is clicked, which is not possible after trying it in the code. (Also, public static void does not recognize the already declared variables inside the class which is a big problem.) I have thought of calling the static void separately in the on click of the button that can be seen in the inspector but maybe because it is a static void, I cannot find it in the options.

This is the code where I am unable to call static int SortByScore in the inspector.

```
static int SortByScore(int snake, int centipede)
{
    return centipede.CompareTo(snake);
}
```

Thank you so so much in advance for the help. :)

Comment: Also, I'm trying to place the value of outcome in a variable so I will be able to know which pattern I will output. For example, if snake is the best fit pattern, I should output its image and meaning. I'm trying to do this like this var best = GetHighestOutcome(); if (best="Snake") { SceneManager.LoadScene("tat_Snake"); } but it says that it cannot convert type string to outcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look into using some sort of `Dictionary` type in order to achieve this.

You want to have a list of values that are tied together so you need an appropriate data type in order to do that. In the solution I propose, we use an `enum` to make a strong type out of the outcomes in your quiz, tying them together by using a `Dictionary` (which is a key-value table) and you can then order these using LINQ to get the outcome.

```
public class QuizScript : MonoBehavior {
    public Dictionary<Outcome, int> Outcomes = new Dictionary<Outcome, int>() {
        { Outcome.Snake, 0 },
        { Outcome.Centipede, 0 }
    };

    public void Q2C1() {
        Outcomes[Outcome.Snake]++;

        Debug.Log("Snake: " + Outcomes[Outcome.Snake]);
    }

    public void Q3C1() {
        Outcomes[Outcome.Centipede]++;

        Debug.Log("Centipede: " + Outcomes[Outcome.Centipede]);
    }

    public Outcome GetHighestOutcome() {
        // Order by the 'key' of the dictionary, i.e. the number we tied to the outcome
        return Outcomes.OrderByDescending(choice => choice.Value).FirstOrDefault().Key;
    }
}

public enum Outcome {
    Snake,
    Centipede
}
```

At OP's additional request, you could do a sort and then get the top items like so:

```
public List<Outcome> GetHighestOutcome() {
    // Order by the 'key' of the dictionary, i.e. the number we tied to the outcome
    var maxValue = Outcomes.OrderByDescending(choice => choice.Value).FirstOrDefault().Value;
    var kvPairs = Outcomes.Find(kv => kv.Value == maxValue);
    return kvPairs.Select(kv => kv.Key).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Definitely approve of the enum instead of string.

Comment: the only answer actually addressing the request for sorting.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry but the OrderByDescending cannot be detected by code. Also, I think this is just a way to get one value, is there a way I can get the top 5 highest values? Thank you again!

Comment: I fixed the OrderByDescending by putting "using System.Linq;". But now I have another concern, how can I call the public Outcome GetHighestOutcome?

Comment: Hi :) I kinda figured it out how to see the outcome through print(GetHighestOutcome()); What I still need though is a probable way to get not just one value but the top five values? Thank you!

Comment: You can get the top x by `OrderByDescending(choice => choice.Value).Take(x);` -> returns the first x items. And than use that in e.g. a foreach loop

Comment: Hi, I did what you said but "return Outcomes.OrderByDescending(choice => choice.Value).Take(x);" indicates an error that says cannot implicitly convert to outcome. Also, I'm trying to place the value of outcome in a variable so I will be able to know which pattern I will output. For example, if snake is the best fit pattern, I should output its image and meaning. I'm trying to do this like this var best = GetHighestOutcome(); if (best="Snake") { SceneManager.LoadScene("tat_Snake"); } but it says that it cannot convert type string to outcome.

Comment: So your first error is because you would need to do `.Take(x)` and then change the return type to be `IEnumerable<Outcome>` or to make it easier for you cast it to a list by doing `blah.Take(x).ToList()` and then change your return type to `List<Outcome>` for your second question you can just compare by `if (best == Choices.Snak) { ... }`. I would look up how to use an enum in C# and figure out how it functions and then how to use it. They are very useful and would serve a good purpose here. However, I would spend more time learning data types and how to use them.

Comment: I have another concern regarding the gethighestoutcome. There are cases that not just only one variable happens to have the highest value, but when this happens the function only shows one variable out of the other variables that have the same value. For example, snake = 3, centipede = 3 and eagle = 1. The highest outcome should be both snake and centipede, but in this case, snake is the only one being shown. Is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a solution for that as well

Comment: Where should I place the value of 5 there so that it will show the top 5 items? Anyway, thank you so much for the help but I have found a solution regarding this by using return Outcomes.OrderByDescending(choice => choice.Value).Skip(1).First().Key; for the top 2nd, return Outcomes.OrderByDescending(choice => choice.Value).Skip(2).First().Key; for the top 3rd so on and so forth.

Comment: I stored their values like this var best = GetHighestOutcome(); for top 1 under public void best1st() and best2 = Get2ndHighestOutcome(); for top 2 under public void best2nd() which are called based on which buttons are clicked. Under these voids are also if else conditions where the variables are compared like if best == Outcome.Snake the picture of snake will be shown.The problem is the showing of top 5 results works at first (which can be seen in the console) when the results button is clicked. But when the button is clicked to show the picture, the top 5 results' values restarts at 0.

Comment: Showing the default arrangement in the dictionary which is the snake, centipede.. even through their not the top 2 highest outcome. What could have been the problem here? Thanks again!

Comment: If you post your updated code then I can help, perhaps create a new question as the scope of the question has changed.

Comment: Hi Sir Tristan, I have created the new question. Thank you so much in advance for the help! :)

Comment: Value of GetHighestOutcome in Dictionary restarting when placed in different public voids? is the title of the question

Answer (score 1):

I think your strategy is getting in-your-way.  This is a good example where you would be better-off storing your values in a `HashSet` or `Dictionary`.

This is how your code would look if you used a Dictionary instead:

```
public class QuizScript : MonoBehaviour {
  public System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, int> characteristic = new Dictionary<string, int>();

  //public int snake = 0;
  //public int centipede = 0;

  //constructor initializes your set
  public QuizScript() {
        characteristic.Add("snake",0);
        characteristic.Add("centipede",0);          
  }

  public void Q2C1() //question 2 choice 1
  {
      characteristic["snake"] += 1;
      Debug.Log("Snake = " + characteristic["snake"].ToString()); //for me to see if it works
  }

  public void Q3C1() //question 3 choice 1
  {
      characteristic["centipede"] += 1;
      Debug.Log("Centipede = " + characteristic["centipede"].ToString());
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you want square brackets, eg `characteristic["snake"] += 1;`

Comment: And what about the sorting the OP asked for in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

What's your goal at the end of the project? Do you want to display the variables in order from biggest to smallest? If so, you could load all the variables into an array, and let the array do the sorting for you. The Array class has a Sort() function!

So, for example, you could have an int array of variables underneath your other variable declarations, then you could load the array with all your variables:

```
variableArray = {snake, centipede, ...} //the rest of your variables
```

Then, use the Array class' Sort function to sort it for you. Check out how to declare an array and how to use Array's Sort function, and you should be all set.

Good luck!

Comment: After sorting the array (however?) how do you know which value belongs to which variable?

Comment: Ah, good point... Tristan's idea with the Dictionary is a better solution.